# Why is this symmetry assertion wrong?

Tags: alloy

I am really confused over why there is always a counter example to my following assertion.

```
//assertions must NEVER by wrong
assert Symmetric{
all r: univ -> univ | some ~r iff (some x, y: univ | x not in y and y not in x and 
                                  (x->y in r) and (y->x in r))
}

check Symmetric
```

The counter-example always shows 1 element in univ set. However, this should not be the case since I specified that there will be some ~r iff x not in y and y not in x. The only element should not satisfy this statement.

Yet why does the model keep showing a counterexample to my assertion?

```
---INSTANCE---
integers={}
univ={Univ$0}
Int={}
seq/Int={}
String={}
none={}
this/Univ={Univ$0}
skolem $Symmetric_r={Univ$0->Univ$0}
```

Would really appreciate some guidance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Alloy, assertions are used to check the correctness of logic sentences (properties of your model), not to specify properties that should always hold in your model.  So you didn't specify that

> there will be some ~r iff x not in y and y not in x

you instead asked Alloy whether it is true that for all binary relations `r`, `some ~r iff x not in y and y not in x [...]`, and Alloy answered that it is not true, and gave you a concrete example (counterexample) in which that property doesn't hold.

A couple other points

- `some ~r` doesn't mean "r is symmetric"; it simply means that the transpose of `r` is non-empty, which is not the same.  A binary relation is symmetric if it is equal to its transpose, so you can write `r = ~r` to express that;
- instead of `some x, y: univ | x not in y and y not in x and [...]` you can equivalently write `some disj x, y: univ | [...]`;
- however, that `some` expression doesn't really express the symmetry property, because all it says is that "there are some x, y such that both x->y and y->x are in r"; instead, you want to say something like "for all x, y, if x->y is in r, then y->x is in r too".